# how to change time format in rails 3.0.1

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

anyone can help me with this?

In my view I have: 
<%= post.time %>

It displays on the screen for the row:
Sat Jan 01 17:18:00 UTC 2000

In every row it says "Sat Jan 01" + "UTC 2000"

How can I get rid of it and display only the time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= post.date.strftime('%H:%M:%S') %>
```

You can read the reference for the full formatting syntax [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392). For example:

**%S** - Second of the minute (00..60)

**%H** - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)

. . . and so on.

Comment: Im sorry but it says "undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Ah... okay, that error message means that your post.date is a Nil object (empty). The formatting method I have given you will work, but it will only work on a real date. It sounds like you do not have the date filled out in your database.

Comment: this is my table. I got entries there too:                          create_table "deadlines", :force => true do |t|  
    t.string   "title"  
    t.text     "content"  
    t.date     "date"  
    t.time     "time"  
    t.integer  "user_id"  
    t.integer  "course_id"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
    t.datetime "updated_at"  
  end

Comment: In my postgre database it says "17:18:00" in the column "time - time without timezone" and in the view "post.date" displays me "Sat Jan 01 17:18:00 UTC 2000"

Comment: Okay, so you've edited your question to use post.time instead of post.date, but strftime('%H:%M:%S') should work equally well with post.time, as long a valid time is returned from the database record that you've given as an example. Have you altered you view to use "post.time" instead?

Comment: Yes I got post.time and post.date in my view. Result is '2014-06-30' for post.time and 'Sat Jan 01 17:18:00 UTC 2000' for post.time

Comment: post.time.strftime(...) is working fine now. Thank you Scott!

Comment: Thanks; That's good to hear it worked out for you... because I'd run out of ideas!

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
  datetime = DateTime.civil(2007, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)   # => Tue, 04 Dec 2007 00:00:00 +0000

  datetime.to_formatted_s(:db)            # => "2007-12-04 00:00:00"
  datetime.to_s(:db)                      # => "2007-12-04 00:00:00"
  datetime.to_s(:number)                  # => "20071204000000"
  datetime.to_formatted_s(:short)         # => "04 Dec 00:00"
  datetime.to_formatted_s(:long)          # => "December 04, 2007 00:00"
  datetime.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  # => "December 4th, 2007 00:00"
  datetime.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)        # => "Tue, 04 Dec 2007 00:00:00 +0000"
```

also you can add your custom format like this:

```
  # config/initializers/time_formats.rb
  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_ordinal] = lambda { |time| time.strftime("%B #{time.day.ordinalize}") }
```